# PayPal Classic API Authenticates one call but not the next

Tags: c#, paypal

I am trying to download transaction history from PayPal.  To do this I am calling `TransactionSearch` to get a basic list of transactions within a date range.  I then call `GetTransactionDetails` to get the full details of each transaction.

```
        using (var client = new PayPalService.PayPalAPIInterfaceClient())
        {
            var credentials = new PayPalService.CustomSecurityHeaderType
            {
                Credentials = new PayPalService.UserIdPasswordType
                {
                    Username = "MyUserName",
                    Password = "MyPassword",
                    Signature = "MySignature"
                }
            };

            TransactionSearchReq request = new TransactionSearchReq();
            request.TransactionSearchRequest = new TransactionSearchRequestType();
            request.TransactionSearchRequest.StartDate = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-12);
            request.TransactionSearchRequest.EndDate = DateTime.Now;
            request.TransactionSearchRequest.Version = "117.0";

            TransactionSearchResponseType transactionSearchResponseType = client.TransactionSearch(ref credentials, request);
            foreach (PaymentTransactionSearchResultType t in transactionSearchResponseType.PaymentTransactions)
            {
                var reqType = new GetTransactionDetailsRequestType
                {
                    TransactionID = t.TransactionID,
                    Version = "117.0"
                };
                reqType.DetailLevel = new DetailLevelCodeType[1];
                reqType.DetailLevel[0] = DetailLevelCodeType.ReturnAll;

                var treq = new GetTransactionDetailsReq
                {
                    GetTransactionDetailsRequest = reqType
                };
                GetTransactionDetailsResponseType transaction = client.GetTransactionDetails(ref credentials, treq);
            }

        }
```

The first call to `TransactionSearch` works and returns me a list of transactions.  The Second call to `GetTransactionDetails` returns an error:

```
Error Code: "10002"
Long Message: "You do not have permissions to make this API call"
Short Message: "Authentication/Authorization Failed"
Correlation ID: 67970b9729a82
Ack: Failure
Build: 000000
Version: "117.0"
Any: null
PropertyChanged: null
```

I have triple check that the `TransactionId` I am passing in the call is one of my valid transactions and it is.

Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: Can you post the complete response from the PayPal including correlation id?

Comment: @Eshan thanks for the response.  I have added more to the post.

Comment: I tried to check at my with this correlation id but was not able to find much . Can you submit the a ticket at www.paypal.com/mts and ping me the ticket here .

Comment: It seems like some how for the "Get Transaction Detail" API the credentials are not being passed . Even though the code includes credentials , can you make sure once that it contains the value ?

Comment: @Eshan you were right, it was losing the credentials for some reason (no idea why it would do that and didn't think to check!).  I set them again before the second call and it works fine now. Put it down as an answer.  Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that some how the credentials are not being passed in your code for the given variables . Make sure below variables contain values :

Username = "MyUserName",
Password = "MyPassword",
Sgnature = "MySignature"

You can hard code the API credentials and then try .